# Error in Excel macro: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel

I have a very basic problem in my excell macros. I recorded a macro with Excell and just selected one sheet on it, as you might imagine, the resulting code is as follows:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Sheets("Graphs").Select
End Sub
```

but when I try to execute the macro above, I get the error: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: If the sheet was hidden or somehow renamed from what you have in your code you would get an error but not that one. I suggest you close all instances of Excel, optionally restart the entire computer, and try again. Repeated crashes made while debugging can destabilize a work environment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that VBA could not determine which object you are referring to.

VBA is good because it is "smart" and allows you to program without specifying exactly what you are referring to.

VBA is bad because of exactly the same reason, because it can be very hard to determine why VBA is not using the object you want it to use unless you know which priorities VBA is using. The same is true not only for objects but also for "implicitly" typed variables, you may want VBA to be handling your variable as a number but VBAs "smartness" is causing it to handle it as a string.

The way around this is to explicitly type want you want VBA to do, in your case VBA is probably trying to reach a sheet named "Graphs" in a different workbook that doesn't have a sheet named "Graphs".

Try this instead:

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim myWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim myWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set myWorkBook = Application.Workbooks("nameofyourworkbook.xlsm")
Set myWorkSheet = myWorkBook.Sheets("Graphs")
myWorkSheet.Select

End Sub
```